# What is the Italian equivalent for "well/so"?

Tags: word-usage, english-comparison, translation

In English we can say:
*Well/So, it's time for me to leave.

So/Well, what can I do to help you?

Well/So, what's the problem?*

Is *allora* an equivalent of "so/well" in these cases?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the first example I'd use "Beh/be', è ora che io vada". For the other sentences "Allora" is fine, but you may also use "Dunque" which however is a bit more rude.

Comment: I find the spelling *beh* too ovine. ;-)

Comment: *beh* is often used as short form of *bene*

Comment: *Beh* for *be'*, *toh* for *to'* and the like are widely used, and - at least the first one - even registered by dictionaries, but are contrary to their etymological origins and, well, ugly.  :-)

Comment: I actually like them (while I hate "bhe" which makes no sense)...

Comment: Free to like them, of course. For me, reading *beh* for *be'* has the same effect it would have if someone were to write *poh* for *po'*.

Comment: Instead of 'Beh' you sould use 'Bene', 'Allora' o 'Quindi'

Answer (score 6):

You may use "bene":

Well/So, it's time for me to leave -> "bene, è ora che me ne vada"

Answer (score 3):

I think that it depends on affirmative-negative or interrogative forms. If you are asking something you can use "Allora dove andiamo?". If you are in the affirmative form you can use "dunque". The expression "Beh" usually is used only when you are speaking and not in written form. Another way to translate this form is "Ehm"; that indicates that you are trying to take time and don't know how to answer: "Ehm, non so se uscirò".

Comment: Your answer is very informative and helpful. Ben fatto!

Answer (score 3):

- It has come the time for something (sudden decision): "bene, beh"
  *Bene/Beh, io vado* (it's time for me to leave).
- You want to push someone to do something or you're annoyed by something: "allora"
  *Allora, andiamo?* (shall we go?)
  *Allora, hai finito?* (have you finished?).
- You want to push someone to take a decision:
  *Bene/beh/allora/dunque, che si fa?* (what should we do now?)
- You are asking something to someone: "bene/allora"
  *Bene/allora, cosa posso fare per lei?*
- You are asking something to someone as a consequence of something said before: "bene/allora/dunque"
  *Bene/allora/dunque, hai preso una decisione?*

Generally speaking:

- **allora** may have a neutral or negative meaning and is mostly used for questions
- **bene** may have a neutral or positive meaning and can be used for both questions and statements
- **beh** usually have a neutral meaning and can be used for both questions and statements
- **bene** and **beh** are often used when something has been just decided
- **dunque** is mostly used for questions, when you want to sum up (allora, bene, beh can be used in the same way)

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: I'd add that _beh_ is a variant of the more etymologically correct _be'_, a truncation of _bene_.